# do I really need to write 'ngInject'

Tags: angularjs

I'm currently refactoring my code to be be compliant with component-base architecture (for further migration to Angular).
Do I really need the `'ngInject'` string and the `$inject` at the end?

In my current code I'm using `ng-annotate` with gulp and it seems like it deals with all the dependencies injection for minifications.

```
   class SecuritySettingsCtrl {
    constructor($scope) {
        'ngInject';
        _self = this;

        _self.$onInit = function () {
            //....
            }

        };
    }

SecuritySettingsCtrl.$inject = ['$scope'];
export default SecuritySettingsCtrl
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need either 'ngInject' (if it configured correctly and works) or .$inject = ...,
or export default ['$scope', ...]

JavaScript minifiers in general know nothing about Angular. So they minify

```
function ctrl($scope) { $scope.name = 'test'}
```

to something like

```
function c(a) { a.name = 'test'}
```

If you add ng-anotate or angularjs-annotate or whatever plugin you like and it works, it will add `ctrl.$inject = ['$scope']` for you, so you have:

```
function c(a) { a.name = 'test'}
c.$inject = ['$scope']
```

If your minified app works - you configured ngInject (or whatever else) correctly.

P.S. Using 'ngInject' together with manual inject `SecuritySettingsCtrl.$inject` of course makes no sense.
"It works" means it works :D you can check it manualy in result minified js file, with test or in real app.

Comment: Can you please explain: _if it configured correctly and works_?